# Using \setmainlanguage{german} after \usepackage{polyglossia} leads to odd-looking capital umlaut letters when using EB Garamond

Tags: xetex, hyphenation, polyglossia, german, ebgaramond

Pay attention to the style of the capital umlaut letters “ÄÖÜ” aud “**ÄÖÜ**” in both cases.

---

**Example 1 (with `\setmainlanguage{german}`):**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},BoldFont=EB Garamond Bold]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{ÄÖÜäöü}
    ÄÖÜäöü \textit{ÄÖÜäöü} \textbf{ÄÖÜäöü} \textbf{\textit{ÄÖÜäöü}}
    
    Jeder hat Anspruch auf die in dieser Erklärung verkündeten Rechte und Freiheiten ohne irgendeinen Unterschied, etwa nach Rasse, Hautfarbe, Geschlecht, Sprache, Religion, politischer oder sonstiger Überzeugung, nationaler oder sozialer Herkunft, Vermögen, Geburt oder sonstigem Stand.
    
    Des Weiteren darf kein Unterschied gemacht werden auf Grund der politischen, rechtlichen oder internationalen Stellung des Landes oder Gebiets, dem eine Person angehört, gleichgültig ob dieses unabhängig ist, unter Treuhandschaft steht, keine Selbstregierung besitzt oder sonst in seiner Souveränität eingeschränkt ist.
\end{document}
```

**Output 1 (with odd-looking “ÄÖÜ” (regular and bold) in inline text but not in the chapter caption):**

[image]

---

**Example 2 (without `\setmainlanguage{german}`):**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},BoldFont=EB Garamond Bold]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
    \chapter*{ÄÖÜäöü}
    ÄÖÜäöü \textit{ÄÖÜäöü} \textbf{ÄÖÜäöü} \textbf{\textit{ÄÖÜäöü}}
    
    Jeder hat Anspruch auf die in dieser Erklärung verkündeten Rechte und Freiheiten ohne irgendeinen Unterschied, etwa nach Rasse, Hautfarbe, Geschlecht, Sprache, Religion, politischer oder sonstiger Überzeugung, nationaler oder sozialer Herkunft, Vermögen, Geburt oder sonstigem Stand.
    
    Des Weiteren darf kein Unterschied gemacht werden auf Grund der politischen, rechtlichen oder internationalen Stellung des Landes oder Gebiets, dem eine Person angehört, gleichgültig ob dieses unabhängig ist, unter Treuhandschaft steht, keine Selbstregierung besitzt oder sonst in seiner Souveränität eingeschränkt ist.
\end{document}
```

**Output 2 (without odd-looking “ÄÖÜ” (regular and bold)):**

[image]

---

I am using the XeTeX compiler. What can I do in order to have a proper German hyphenation as shown in output 1 and non-odd-looking capital umlaut letters as shown in output 2?

Comment: well you get lots of warnings in the log. You could try `Language=Default,Script=Default` in the font features.

Comment: This has solved the problem. Thank you! I will look at the log and try to solve the problems that occur there.